# Why I saw this error HTTP 500 component definition not found

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven, zk

I downloaded a SecureLogin project because I want to insert it in my project.
I made my project with a theme that I have downloaded from github.
Both of project are build with maven.

If I launch both project, both works correctely.
Now, I paste all my theme webapp project in webapp folder in SecureLogin project.
I want that after the login, my controlpanel will be appear.

But after I try to run controlpanel.zul I saw this:

HTTP Status 500 - file:/C:/xampp...gin/applications/index.zul:44:45: Component definition not found: navbar in [LanguageDefinition: xul/html]

and many many exceptions!

Probably there is a problem with pom.xml because seems that he doesn't found some library. But, if I copy some part of MyTheme's pom in SecureLogin's pom I will see HTTP ERROR 404 when I try to launch index.zul of SecureLogin.

How can I merge the two project? Thanks for answer

Comment: First try to get some understanding about the other project. Do not just copy blindly.

Comment: MyTheme project is a project from github that I have correctly modified and now works as I want. Now I don't know what other I have to import

Answer (score 0):

Check your pom.xml (or perhaps Maven Dependency Tree) in the original two and the merged projects. Perhaps the ZK Versions are different.

Note that Navbar is in the commercial EE edition in ZK 7.